# Cant store a message on a method in java with exceptions

Tags: java, exception

My code needs to store the message given to MiExepcion on getmessage, but it's not working.
The code is:

```
package act5_3;

public class act5_3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            MiExcepcion e = new MiExcepcion("Este es mi propio error.");
            throw e;
        } catch (MiExcepcion e) {
            //Error in the next line
            //method in getmessage in class MiExcepcion cannot be applied to given types.
            System.out.println("Excepción: " + e.getmessage());
        }
    }
}

//Declarin Exception
class MiExcepcion extends Exception {
    public MiExcepcion(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    //method to store given message
    public String getmessage(String message) throws MiExcepcion {
        return message;
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your code is without any indentations making it all left justified and almost impossible to read, understand and debug. Please re-format your posted code by giving it proper indentations, usually 4 spaces per block, and making sure that all code on the same block is on the same indentation level. Your cooperation in this would be greatly appreciated and will likely improve your chances of getting a decent and prompt answer.

Comment: The Exception class already has a `getMessage()` method. Why not just use it?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception class already has a getMessage() method. Why not just use it?

```
public class Foo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
         MiExcepcion e = new MiExcepcion("Este es mi propio error.");
         throw e;
      } catch (MiExcepcion e) {
         System.out.println("Excepción: " + e.getMessage());
      }
   }
}

class MiExcepcion extends Exception {
   public MiExcepcion(String message) {
      super(message);
   }

   // Not needed
   // public String getmessage(String message)throws MiExcepcion
   // {
   // return message;
   // }
}
```

Note that capitalization matters, and that `getmessage()` will not work while `getMessage()` will.

Comment: I know, but I was asked to create a method for that.

Comment: @JosuéZatarain: post the specific requirement of your assignment because I have a feeling that you may be misunderstanding what you're supposed to be doing. Also, and again, please format your code better.

Comment: @JosuéZatarain: `public String getMessage() { super.getMessage();}` will work just fine if you need to create your own method.

Answer (score 0):

While you could use `Exception.getMessage` as Hovercraft said, the problem with your code seems perfectly clear to me.

You declared the method `getmessage(String message)` which accepts a string as an argument, but when calling it in your main class, you do not pass it any argument. Its a surprise to me this code is even compiling... And that is probably the meaning of the exception thrown to you which is most likely `NoSuchMethodException`.

Next time please post stack trace of the exception.